# Jest test failing because of missing dynamic import in angular 10 when testing component with quill editor in it

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, ngx-quill

I am writting test for an angular component and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError [ERR_VM_DYNAMIC_IMPORT_CALLBACK_MISSING]: A dynamic import callback was not specified.
TypeError [ERR_VM_DYNAMIC_IMPORT_CALLBACK_MISSING]: A dynamic import callback was not specified.

  at QuillService.<anonymous> (projects/ngx-quill/src/lib/quill.service.ts:26:29)
  at step (node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:102:23)
  at Object.next (node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:83:53)
```

The component containt a sub-component which wrap a quill editor and the tests on the sub-component have no issues. I can't find anything missing between the two tests files.

The wierd thing is that the 'it should create' test pass but any other wont.